# ImageView with Lottie animation inside layout - problem with ClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I've created my custom View class:

```
class CustomCheckBox constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs), Checkable {

    private var checked: Boolean = false

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this)
        
    }

    fun setCheckedAnim(check: Boolean) {
        isChecked = check
        animation.playAnimation()
    }

    fun toggleAnim(check: Boolean) {
        toggle(check)
        animation.playAnimation()
    }

    override fun setChecked(value: Boolean) {
        checked = value
        checkbox.isChecked = value
    }

    override fun isChecked(): Boolean = checked

    override fun toggle() {
        checked = !checked
        checkbox.isChecked = checked
    }
 
}
```

Layout is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@drawable/toggle_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/animation_json"
        app:lottie_speed="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="false"
        app:lottie_loop="false"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem I am facing is that when I set `ClickListener` for this `View` in code, the Listener doesn't work. It happens because `CheckBox` captures every click.
 If I create custom `ClickListener` and set is as listener for `CheckBox` then it works fine but the true problem is that I need this listener to be set for my main `View` using `setOnClickListener()` so the `View` has it, not it's component. It's because later in code I am checking `if (listener != null)` that's why it has to have it's own listener which will work.

Comment: Either override `setOnClickListener(l: OnClickListener?)` for the custom view or add a new method to it, say `setOnViewClickListener(...)`.

Comment: I've tried everything. Added custom ClickListener as an interface, implemented OnClickListener for CheckBox, even tried to use `performClick()` for my View inside checkbox listener